# Calculator implemented in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I've been trying to figure out what is wrong with my code, I need to add the products (bananas, sodas, chips, candy) then multiply it with 10% tax given. Am I missing the variables for those products? I know something is missing but I don't know what to do!

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Total Calculator</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      Bananas: <input type="text" id="bananasBox" value="" /> at $ 0.50 a piece<br/>
      Sodas: <input type="text" id="sodasBox" value="" /> at $ 0.75 per can<br/>
      Chips: <input type="text" id="chipsBox" value="" /> at $1.25 per bag<br/>
      Candy: <input type="text" id="candyBox" value="" /> at $1.00 per pack<br/>
      TAX is 10 %
    </p>
    
    <button id="Calculate" onclick= "Calculate()" value="Calculate">Calculate</button>

    <script>
      function Calculate(){
        var total = 0;
        var cost = document.getElementById("cost").value;
        var tax = document.getElementById("tax").value;

        total = cost * tax;
        document.getElementById("total").value = total;

        document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML= "Your TOTAL is: " + total;
      }
    </script>
    <hr/>
    <div id="outputDiv"> 
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: so what is the error? what is the current behavior?

Comment: I dont see any controls with id's `cost`, `tax` or `total` which are being used in your JS code. Your JS code seems completely out of sync with your actual HTML. Either change the id's of the controls that you want to use or change the JS code to get the values from the correct controls

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you really put forth any effort, but here's a correct answer:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Total Calculator </title>
</head>
<body>
<p>
Bananas:   <input type="text" id="bananasBox" value=""> at $ 0.50 a piece<br>
Sodas  :   <input type="text" id="sodasBox"   value=""> at $ 0.75 per can<br>
Chips  :   <input type="text" id="chipsBox"   value=""> at $1.25 per bag<br>
Candy  :   <input type="text" id="candyBox"   value=""> at $1.00 per pack<br>
TAX is 10 %
</p>
<input type="button" value="Calculate" id='Calculate' onclick= "Calculate()">
<script type="text/javascript">


function Calculate() {
    var total = 0;
    var bananas = Number(document.getElementById("bananasBox").value) * .5;
    var sodas = Number(document.getElementById("sodasBox").value) * .75;
    var chips = Number(document.getElementById("chipsBox").value) * 1.25;
    var candy = Number(document.getElementById("candyBox").value) * 1;
    var tax = 0.10;

    total = (bananas+sodas+chips+candy)*(1+tax);
document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML= 'Your TOTAL is: $' + Number(total).toFixed(2);
}
</script>
<hr>
<div id="outputDiv"> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want me to explain it I will, but if you don't really have any intention in learning: it wouldn't be worth wasting my time.

Comment: Well, the intention of me  asking this question AFTER creating this code IS to learn. But, if you dont want to explain thats fine, you can save your "time". :) @Rhyono Its not that I didnt try, I did know something was missing, I did know it was the variables but what I did not know is how to put the var + the value as a code.

Comment: The reason I do not believe you put much effort forth and why so many people have downvoted your question is because of how basic your question is. You made extremely simple mistakes that I do not believe anyone would have made after actually trying to learn from a tutorial or by any other means. You had the concept of fetching input down, but you were attempting to fetch it from `cost` (which didn't exist) and not from the boxes that did. I can add to my answer if you do not understand the code I have provided.